# How do I see the complete URL once I submit a request?

Tags: javascript, html, http, firebug

How do I see the complete URL once I submit a request?

I am trying to access the complete list of schools using the 
site http://directory.acswasc.org/
and then clicking on submit search button which gives page by
page listing of schools.

But I am not able to see the complete URL used to get the result.

If I can somehow get the complete URL with parameters,
I can then use the python request API on the URL to get the data.

Please let me know how I construct the URL in this case.

I debugged the request using Firebug Firefox plugin:

http://directory.acswasc.org/directory-searchlist.php?hid_CategoryName=&hid_CountyRegionName=&hid_PageCount=-1&hid_PageNum=1&hid_PageStart=1&hid_SchoolCount=-1&selcategory=0&selcounty=0&txtCity=&txtSchoolName=

but I am getting zero results. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page uses the POST HTTP method to send the data. Using that request method parameters are not send within the URL but rather [enclosed in the body of the request message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29).

Firebug displays POST parameters in the *Post* tab of the request. They are displayed in a formatted way, but also as source below that, which is probably what you need.

[image: POST request parameters shown in Firebug's *Post* tab]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification.

Comment: Note that if an answer on Stack Overflow helped you, you normally upvote it or you accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It likely uses POST data. View that in firebug and see if that's it.